# Void method is not running automatically when my project runs

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, devexpress, xaf

i want to run my void method automatically when my project runs but it doesn't. i tried this but i think this is not good way. what is another way or how i can initialize my void method.

```
string fAccount;
[Key]
[Size(150)]
public string Account
{
    get { GroupedAccount(); return fAccount; }
    set { SetPropertyValue<string>(nameof(Account), ref fAccount, value); }
}
private void GroupedAccount()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Traders", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Open();
        var groupedData = from b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          group b by b.Field<string>("Account Name") into g
                          select new
                          {
                              fAccounts = g.Key,
                          };

        foreach (var r in groupedData)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.TradersAccount (Account) VALUES (@Account)", conn);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", r.fAccounts);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why not call `GroupedAccount` in the startup code of your app?

Comment: Also, read up on `using` and how it relates to `IDisposable`.

Comment: You also appear to be reading data from one table and inserting it (one row at a time) to another. This makes not much sense. Have a think about how to do this **in a single SQL statement** instead (something like `INSERT INTO dbo.TradersAccount (Account) SELECT Distinct [Account Name] From Traders`). It will be **way** faster.

Comment: It is also _very_ odd to do database inserts inside a property's getter.

Comment: the problem is also that the start up code doesn't exist this is xaf(devexpress) framework project and its different. i'm new about xaf

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q582348/startup-code

Comment: >>the problem is also that the start up code doesn't exist this is xaf(devexpress) framework project and its different. 

XAF apps are regular .NET WinForms and ASP.NET WebForms apps, so their YourSolutionName.Wxx projects have the typical Program.xx and Global.asax.xx files for your startup code. XAF requires general WinForms and ASP.NET knowledge to get started or for the best results.

I agree with @shamp00 that you better not do it in your current way, because it is very unnatural. For more information on XAF and XPO, see 
 https://youtu.be/184fsA_gSYg and https://youtu.be/SCPho8CgalY

Answer (score 1):

In an XAF application, you have several places to put startup code, but in your case it looks like you are trying to initialize some objects in the database based on some existing data. The recommended place for this is the `ModuleUpdater` in the *Updater.cs* file. See the documentation for more information:

- [Create and update the application's database](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113185/concepts/business-model-design/create-and-update-the-application's-database)
- [Supply Initial Data for XPO](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112788/getting-started/comprehensive-tutorial/business-model-design/business-model-design-with-xpo/supply-initial-data-xpo).

Your `Account` property is part of an XPO object. XPO is an object relational mapper, that is, it abstracts away the complexities of transferring your C# classes to SQL storage. In general you should refrain from putting *any* additional code in the getters and setters of persisted properties. The DevExpress documentation is good:

- [Ways to add a business class](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112847/concepts/business-model-design/business-model-design-with-xpo/ways-to-add-a-business-class)
- [Comprehensive XAF Tutorial](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112560/getting-started/comprehensive-tutorial-maindemo-application).
- [XPO best practices](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2944/xpo-best-practices)

In particular, XPO is intended to dispense with the need for direct SQL. If you need `TradersAccount` objects to be created or updated whenever an `Trader` object is modified, then you would normally create a `TraderAccount` XPO object and define an [association property](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2041/concepts/relationships-between-objects) and create it with `new TraderAccount(Session)` and add it to the association property collection. Then XPO will automatically generate all of the corresponding SQL for you.